# Installing GEMs out of a local directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm working in a enterprise environment with no real internet access. I have to maintain several ruby applications that are all based on the default ruby distribution with a few additional gems that vary from application to application. I can't set up a server-based gem repository, but i can have a shared directory on one of the main servers to store my gems (which in it self was a fight to get).

I know that I can install a gem by just doing a

```
gem install pfad/gemfile-version.gem
```

What does not seem to work is whole version selection mechanic. Shouldn't

```
gem install gemfile -v version -i pfad
```

work?

And setting GEM_PATH isn't helpful too. Let's have a real world example

`gem install i:\rufus-scheduler-3.0.8.gem`

works,

```
set GEM_PATH=i:\
gem install rufus-scheduler -v ">=3.0"
```

says

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rufus-scheduler' (>= 0) in any repository
```

I tried "bundler" instead, wrote a "gemfile"

```
source "i:\"
gem "rufus-scheduler", ">=3.0"
```

to no avail.

Right now it looks to me that all this gem business is written for a minority of users and is not really working in the real world :/

Can anyone show me my errors or point me to a better solution? I like the concept behind having a 'gemfile', but what is the use if I can't use it to install gems?!?

EDIT:

It seems that gems does work in several distinctive steps:

- fetch xml description of repository
- search tag in xml for specified criteria (version, platform, etc.)
- fetch in tag specified *.gem-file
- install *.gem-file

If there is no internet access or you use "--local" only the last step is available. It seems that someone implemented the first 3 steps as monolithic block. At least I found no way to introduce a local xml gem repository description into the process. In my eyes a design error that makes the whole filter process for gems useless except for very special and rare use cases.

Comment: have you looked at this: http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/installing-gems-with-no-network?

Comment: yes, but that also doesn't bring versions into account. It, like i said in my first example, does install specific gem files, but it seems not to work with "-v".

Comment: I don't see `:path => '/foo/bar/' anywhere, is that relevant?`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I think you mean in the context of the 'gemfile', yes? The specc for the 'gemfile' is here http://bundler.io/v1.6/man/gemfile.5.html . According to this I read that :path requires "... that you specify an explicit version that bundler should use." Which actually again means that I can't use eg. "~>3.0".